# mongodb query vs mysql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I have the following MySQL query in which I have done sum profit which I have fields like: rate, credit(money)

```
SELECT SUM((credit*(100-rate))/100) FROM roznamcha WHERE  (accountNum=$id AND rate!=0.0)'
```

I have written the following query in mongodb using node.js but it returns null whoever I have some data in my database

```
    const profit=await roznamcha.aggregate([  
        {
            $match:{
                rate:{$ne:0}
            }
        },
        {
            $group:{
                _id :'$accountNum',
            }
        },
        {
        $addFields:{
                resultMultiply:{
                   $divide:[
                       {$multiply:['$credit','$rate-$100']},100
                   ]

                },
    sumcredit:{
        $sum:'$resultMultiply'
    }
         } }
        
    ])
    res.status(201).json({
        status:'success',
       
        data:{
           profit
        }
    })
```

**My output:**

```
    {
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "profit": [
            {
                "_id": "612deac8fbc8ef21a0fa4ea7",
                "resultMultiply": null,
                "sumcredit": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "612223327e2af83a4cec1272",
                "resultMultiply": null,
                "sumcredit": 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const roznamchaSchem=mongoose.Schema({
    accountNum: {
        type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:'account',
        required: ['please specify this record is from who', true],
    },
    credit: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    debit: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    rate: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
description:{
        type:String,
        required:['description can not be empty',true],
        minlength: 8
    },
    issueDate:{
            type: Date,
            required:['add an valide date',true]
}
});
roznamchaSchem.index({accountNum:-1});
const Roznamcha=mongoose.model('roznamcha',roznamchaSchem);
module.exports=Roznamcha;
```

and my example of document:

```
id:612f533e8eb5533f303966e4
credit:50
debit:0
rate:2
accountNum:612deac8fbc8ef21a0fa4ea7
description:"this it for you"
issueDate:6543-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

can anyone guide me in solving this query?

Comment: Can you add your schema model and a sample of document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides @Joe and @Nenad answer the **error for the subtraction: '$rate-$100'**;

You need to re-position your logic structure.

1. Perform calculation: `SUM((credit*(100-rate))/100)`.
2. Group by `$accountNum` and aggregate `SUM` for `resultMultiply`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      rate: {
        $ne: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      resultMultiply: {
        $divide: [
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$credit",
              {
                "$subtract": [
                  100,
                  "$rate"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$accountNum",
      total: {
        $sum: "$resultMultiply"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

> Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "total": 1.5
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "total": 5.5
  }
]
```

[Sample MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JeL4OnOinAa)

Comment: why i can not add the $sum in $addfiled stage?

Comment: Because as your MongoDB query, without doing sum aggregate in group stage, you will not able to sum the `resultMultiply` by `accountNum`.

Answer (score 2):

`'$rate-$100'` is referring to a field named "rate-$100".  You probably meant to subtract using

```
{$subtract: [ 100, "$rate"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use mathematical operator **minus** for substraction, you have to use `$subtract` aggregation operator.

```
resultMultiply: {
  $divide: [{
      $multiply: [
        "$credit",
        { $subtract: [ 100, "$rate" ] }
      ]
    },
    100
  ]
}
```

Comment: i change minus to $subtract but i still return null

Comment: Can you add the Schema Model and example of the document in your question?

Comment: i edit my question and also i want to say i think it is problem with my variable like credit and rate when i change my variable with numbers it gave me a valid out put