# mongoDB aggregate query vs MySQl query

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have following MySQL query in which I have done sum profit which i have fields like: rate, credit(money) an I want to by finding total of credit*(100-rate))/100 for a specific id reach to profit of a person money.

```
SELECT SUM((credit*(100-rate))/100) FROM roznamcha WHERE  (accountNum=$id AND rate!=0.0)'
```

I have written following query in mongodb using node.js but it return null whoever i have some data in my database

```
const profit=await roznamcha.aggregate([  
    {
        $match:{
            rate:{$ne:0}
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id :'$accountNum',
        }
    },
    {
    $addFields:{
            resultMultiply:{
               $divide:[
                   {$multiply:['$credit','$rate-$100']},100
               ]

            },
sumcredit:{
    $sum:'$resultMultiply'
}
     } }
    
])
res.status(201).json({
    status:'success',
   
    data:{
       profit
    }
})
```

my outpue:

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
    "profit": [
        {
            "_id": "612deac8fbc8ef21a0fa4ea7",
            "resultMultiply": null,
            "sumcredit": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "612223327e2af83a4cec1272",
            "resultMultiply": null,
            "sumcredit": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

can anyone guide me in solving this query?

Comment: its the group, after the group you will have only 1 field the `_id`, if you want to group and keep also the document fields add those fields in the group using `$first` accumulator  for example

Comment: Duplicate to this question: [mongodb query vs mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69010121/mongodb-query-vs-mysql)?

Comment: yes it is just a mistake sorry for that @YongShun

Answer (score 0):

In the $group section add these code:

```
{
        $group:{
            _id :'$accountNum',
            "credit":{$first:"$credit"},
            "rate":{$first:"$rate"}

        }
    }
```

I think this portion Mongo query will help you out because you are not getting values of credit and rate, hence it was showing null.
now you add these values then it would calculate the percentage.

NOTE: you just use the divide and conquer method to run your code when the Mongo query is there, where you should execute the 1st block of the query, if required data is shown then move to the second part, and so on.

Hope you will get the answer